# why child element <img /> not contains in the parent div width and height?

Tags: css, image, html

everyone I try the css style as below:

```
.image{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color:green;
    }
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.wallpapersgo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Dodge-Charger-Car.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

The problem is, the showing image is same size as it is, but not in a expected size as 100px * 100px. 
fresh in css style, need help , thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
.image{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color:green;
    }

.image img {       
        width: inherit;
        height:inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.image img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p67dh/

This is because your image don't use automatically the size of the parent element.